# 'Apalike' bibliography style not responding correctly

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I had written a M.Sc thesis using Latex. After my oral defence, I tried to effects some of the correction but to my surprise the reference listing in the bibliography changed. I did not alter the bibliographystyle I had initially used. My preamble and bibliography style are given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliographystyle{astron}
%\bibliographystyle{harvard}
%\bibliographystyle{plain} %% plain.bst
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
%\bibliographystyle{bbs}
%\bibliographystyle{siam}
%\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
```

I want a listing that will look like this:

> Ying, Q., M., Mysliwiec, and M. J. Kleeman, (2004) Source
>   apportionment of visibility      impairment using a three-dimensional
>   source-oriented air quality model. Environmental Science &Technology,
>   38: 1089-1101.

---

> Ying, Q. and Kleeman, M.J. (2006) Source contributions to the regional
>   distribution of secondary particulate matter in California.
>   Atmospheric Environment, 40: 736-752.

---

> Yuanxun, Z., Yuanmao, Z., Yingsong, W., Delu, L., Aiguo, L., Yan, L.,
>   Guilin, Z., Yifei, Z. and Zuci, S. (2006) PIXE Characterization of
>   PM10 and PM2.5 Particulate Matter Collected during the Winter Season
>   in Shanghai City. J. Radioanal. Nucl. Chem., 267: 497–499.

But the lines after the first will be indented.

I am stucked now, please assist. Do I need to install a package for apalike or what is really happening.

Comment: If the `apalike` package is not installed, the document you posted will generate an error along the lines of: `! LaTeX Error: File `apalike.sty' not found.`  (Of course, I suspect it *is* installed on your system.)  You should provide a working minimal example [see here](http://tinyurl.com/43pgxu7) that shows the problem.  If I fix your example to make it compilable, it runs fine, though the style of the bibliography might not be to your needs.  You may want to consider using [biblatex](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html), or one of its many contributed styles.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the hanging indentation of second and subsequent lines of bibliographic entries entirely while using the `natbib` package, the instruction you need to issue in your document's preamble, after loading the `natbib` package, is:

```
\setlength\bibindent{0pt}  % default value: 1em
```

Conversely, if you *do* want some hanging indentation, say by the amount of `2em`, you'd type:

```
\setlength\bibindent{2em}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants a hanging indent in the bibliography (though I suppose @Segun can see how easily your suggestion could be adapted to change the indent to any length he desires).

Comment: Thanks, @jon. I'll revise my answer to indicate this explicitly.