# bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Apalike' bibliography style not responding correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38457/apalike-bibliography-style-not-responding-correctly)

I am writing an M.Sc thesis. I have used LaTeX for the preparation of the thesis. But after my oral defense, when I try to do the corrections, the bibliography style gave a different format. I did not alter the bibliography style I used initial. My preamble and bibliography style are given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{subeqn}
%\usepackage{varioref,hyperref}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliographystyle{astron}
%\bibliographystyle{harvard}
%\bibliographystyle{plain} %% plain.bst
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
%\bibliographystyle{bbs}
%\bibliographystyle{siam}
%\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
```

Do I need to install `apalike` package or what really is the problem. Could anyone be kind enough to assist me urgently. I have an ultimatum to meet.
I have tried various thing, I even tried the other bibliographystyle but the referencing was done in just a particular style.
I actual want a style that will indent the lines after the first, write and in lieu of & and and also cite the references in the body of the thesis in the author year format.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with some bibliography entries.

Comment: Is this question the same: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38457/apalike-bibliography-style-not-responding-correctly

Comment: I suggest to close the question , as it is exactly the same question as the one mentionned by Marco Daniel, and by the same author. It is a duplicate.